# angular 2 full page component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

A regular page has the header, and the body controlled by `<router-outlet>`

I want a specific component, when navigated to, to be the root component on the page, without any header. Is there a way to tell angular about that?

I could theoretically put code in all other components like header, that would hide when this specific component is active, but I'd rather something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. you can use different router outlets. The root page will have the basics, and the root `router-outlet`. It will navigate to a common sub root page, which will have headers, footers, all the, stuff, and its own `router-outlet`. Most of the navigation will be done on the leaf's router-outlet, however when you want to navigate to a full page component, you will use the root router outlet, and leave the sub root.